Is there a way to assign a shortcut or hotkey to open action list like open blender file dialogue i think CTL + SHIFT + O
hay,
I need to know if there a way to open action list to apply an action to selected armature like when we try to open a blender file there's a hotkey that open recent file dialogue box, can i open action list like that and can i assign a hotkey to switch between add brush during skinning and remove or mix brush
i tried chat GPT, forums and google but couldn't find any answer
